# Downsize CPU & DB usage in wordpress

Tags: performance, memory, wp-blog-header.php

i have created a smart interface WP based which we use to manage clients..
it uses a lot of information and data each time a client is returned / viewed.

**it is a locked interface and does not have traffic spikes**

in the past month i have seen major memory and CPU usage spikes so,
i have installed the debug bar and opended all the options.

What i am seeing is that each time wordpress includes wp-header-blog
and template-loader (or am i wrong?) - can i declare those once?

**here is an example from the queries tab in the debug bar**

```
'clientsocialurls'
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/category.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/tabs/tab-siteinfo.php'), get_page_by_title #47 (14.4ms)
SELECT ID FROM armnd_posts WHERE post_title = 'זמנהוף שירותי תרגום' AND post_type= 'cheques'

require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/category.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/tabs/tab-cheques.php'), get_page_by_title #48 (3.9ms)
SELECT armnd_posts.* FROM armnd_posts WHERE 1=1 AND armnd_posts.post_type = 'attachments' AND (armnd_posts.post_status = 'publish') ORDER BY armnd_posts.post_date ASC 

require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/category.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/tabs/tab-attachments.php'), get_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts #49 (34.7ms)
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM armn_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (2073,2086,2093,2104,2109,2114,2119,2137,2143,2148,2154,2160,2165,2174,2178,2186,2274,2650,2708,3163,3356,3507,3644,3673,3893,3924,4039,4139,4286,4311,4515,4596,4666,4698,4722,4738,4740,4841,4860,4908,5219,5941,6086,6317) ORDER BY meta_id ASC

require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/category.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/tabs/tab-attachments.php'), get_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, update_post_caches, update_postmeta_cache, update_meta_cache #50 (9.9ms)
SELECT armnd_posts.* FROM armnd_posts WHERE 1=1 AND armnd_posts.post_parent = 2119 AND armnd_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND (armnd_posts.post_status = 'inherit') ORDER BY armnd_posts.post_date DESC 

require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/category.php'), include('/themes/sagive-manager/tabs/tab-attachments.php'), get_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts
```

**does this means wordpress loads both files each time a query is called?**
can i "Declare" them once to minimize memory usage and load time?

am i completlty missing the point and can you share some tips to downsize
the CPU usage & memory usage if its a given i cant use caching plugin.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does a query have to do with spike in memory and CPU usage?

Comment: i admit i am lacking in that area... but as i have read across multiple blogs / articles each query and especially when we are talking about 500+ chokes the memory and cpu usage since its tasking the server to retrieve data and holds it before displaying it in the memory. i would love some information to correct my view / teach me more (searched!) - the same as plugins create additional resources use so does queries.

Comment: In general a long query might cause a cpu/mem usage spike but that is only for the duration of the generation of the specific page. If you see spikes via monitoring tools it means that the problem continues for at least several minutes. If the site usage pattern haven't changed during the spikes then the most logical explanation is that the site has more visitors but if the spikes correlate with usage changes then maybe yu have to optimize the specific pages that are slow, which means that you have to identify them first....

Comment: thanks mate, i have optimized the pages in all other regards aka images, minify, minimizing the code and other stuff... The only thing i have left is to minize un-neccesery queries - the uppercode is a print-out of the debug toolbar plugin... i was wondering if the wp-blog-header.php and template-loader.php is actually loading time after time and how to prevent it.

Comment: yes they are loading on each page generation. Best way to prevent them from loading is to use caching ;)

Comment: i cant cache the entire page - it returns dynamic information (even each part of it)... can i declare them once?

Comment: To handle CPU and mem spikes you need more hardware. Your client might decide that he prefers a possible out of date info then paying more for the server. anyway this gets too far away from the original question....

Comment: This was actually the original question! but, nice chatting mate ;) - thanks for the intreset and your attempt to help.

Comment: debug bar output is just showing you backtrace information for each query so you know the path to how that query was generated, it's not loading those files repeatedly.

Comment: I should have been more explicit... the reason it doesn't advance helping you optimize the site is because there are not enough details to advice anything, and if you have a traffic spike then nothing can help. If the question is only about which files are loaded then it is a case of too much details ;)

Comment: ohh ;) - your right - added that information to the question... its a locked interface so no traffic spikes... i guess i am looking for a way to "declare those files" and others as global / Make wordpress include them only once (and other system files in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sagive,

1. `wp-blog-header.php` loaded in the `index.php` on each page request. AJAX calls included (if that's what you mean "time after time".
   Then it loads `template-loader.php`.
2. This has nothing to do with the SQLs you see, and not with the "spikes".
3. Install the Query Monitor plugin to see your SQLs better in the Debug Bar.
4. Do not publish sensitive information here (like the name of your client in the first SQL).  :-)

Comment: thanks ;) - this is an output from my localhost so.. the path's are different. - i am wondering how to call these files only once. even if i have 20 ajax files loading into the same page?

Comment: p.s thanks for stopping by gregory, i am following you on g+ and got your site bookmarked ;)

Comment: Altough not a solution - pointing out that each ajax file (and i created a lot to keep things organized) loads wp-blog-header & template-loader - is a direction to minimize the ajax files into as few as possible which is helpfull - thanks again ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a stateless protocol and it will initialize the whole WordPress system each time a request hits any page in the server. Scripts like wp-blog-header.php, template-loader etc are required to properly initialize WordPress.

Comment: so... it cant be done? i cant load those files for each ajax file and each query? i am missing some information... why does it seem that WP requires those files on each query?

Comment: These are not each query.. rather each request to server( be it AJAX too) will need these files.